# Shifting The React Router DOM Version Confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm shifting to react-router-dom v6 from react-router-dom v5. But there is something I wanna do but I'm not sure of it. As the Redirect Component is not found in the react-router-dom v6 and you gotta use the navigate.

This is the code i'm getting confused on:

```
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authenticated ? (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: `/dashboard`, state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
```

So in this case, would you like to help me out?